# Restoring File From Temp Folder To Original Folder And File Name

Tags: vb.net

I move a file to the temp folder (Path.GetTempPath). Later, the user wishes to restore the file to its original location using an application option. I can get the file name without any trouble.  How do I get the original file path?  In the file properties there is a Path item but it is always the current path. Since I am already setting an EXIF tag, I thought of using some other EXIF tag with the original path and file name. EXIF seems counter productive and there must be another way. I have looked at similar questions but none seem to solve this issue.

Comment: You need to store original paths somewhere - file system itself has no knowledge of previous locations. If you need to restore file inside current session only, then some in-memory collection should be enough; if you need to find your files after reopening your app, then you need some kind of database solution.

Comment: Thanks.  I put a folder in the temp file where any application temp files are stored.  I will just add a Dictionary with the filename as key and the original path as data.  A little bit more work to maintain the dictionary  but not too bad.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just put another file in the temp folder with the same name, different extension and inside it put the original location?

```
Dim toMove = "c:\myfolder\some.txt"

Dim temp = Path.GetTempFileName()              'string of eg c:\user\appdata\temp\file.tmp..
Dim loc = Path.ChangeExtension(temp, "loc")    'string of eg c:\user\appdata\temp\file.loc..

File.Move(toMove, temp)                        'move c:\myfolder\some.txt -> c:\user\appdata\temp\file.tmp
File.WriteAllText(loc, toMove)                 'write "c:\myfolder\some.txt" string into file at c:\user\appdata\temp\file.loc
```

And then to move it back

```
Dim toMoveBack = "..some tmp file path.."            'e.g. c:\user\appdata\temp\file.tmp
Dim loc = Path.ChangeExtension(toMoveBack, "loc")    'e.g. c:\user\appdata\temp\file.loc
Dim origLoc = File.ReadAllText(loc)                  'origLoc is now a value of c:\myfolder\some.txt


File.Move(toMoveBack, origLoc)                       'move c:\user\appdata\temp\file.tmp -> c:\myfolder\some.txt 
File.Delete(loc)                                     'remove c:\user\appdata\temp\file.loc
```

Comment: The files are all JPEG image files and I do not want to change the file extension.  The dictionary seems to work pretty well.

Comment: I'm not sure of the relevance of your comment. You said you wanted to move the, to a temp folder, and you clearly have a mechanism for doing so. I used Path.GetTempFilename because I don't know what your mechanism is, it just demonstrates a way to get a filename to a temp folder. Path.ChangeExtension does not rename a file. It takes a string like "c:\whatever\my.jpg" and returns a string like "c:\whatever\my.loc". With the code above you end up with 2 files in the file system, one being eg "c:\temp\my.jpg" and the other being "c:\temp\my.loc", a text file containing eg "c:\whatever\my.jpg"

Comment: Thus, it is the file system that is remembering where the jpg (still called jpg) in the temp folder, used to live. For a 123.jpg in the temp folder there will be a 123.loc file containing a path string of eg "c:\old\path\for\123.jpg"

Comment: ps, I also understood "later" to mean "days later, the user having shut their computer down in the mean time" - if there's a chance your user could end up thinking they've lost files because your program crashed after moving them and before moving them back you should take some steps to ensure that some transient thing like a crash or power loss doesn't affect the memory of where the files were

Comment: Thanks.  I tried  what you suggested.  I may be missing something.  The file after being moved to the temp folder has the path of the temp location not the original path.  I am putting the file in a temp location in case the EXIF processing has an error.  Then it gets deleted.  However, I rethought what I am doing and decided on a different approach altogether (no temp files).    Thanks for your suggestions though.

Comment: *The file after being moved to the temp folder* - which file ? There are two in my proposal. Be careful you get the WriteAllText arguments the correct way round. I added comments to the algorithm